# multivariate Kernel Density Estimator with independent bandwidth for each dimension

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels, scipy-optimize, kernel-density

I found several types of KDEs implementations on python, but still I cannot find one version that is flexible regarding the kernel used and that can use different bandwidth per dimension. This actually is available in MATLAB's `mvksdensity()`.

```
scipy.stats.multivariate_normal
scipy.stats.kde
scipy.stats.gaussian_kde
```

are for some types of kernel only, and bw is the same in all dimensions.

```
sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity
```

this one seems like the best candidate, I love how it works, but bandwidth is also global.

```
statsmodels.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate
```

bandwidth are different per dimension, but it seems a bit limited, for example, I cannot choose the kernel other than gaussian, cuadratic or uniform afaik...

Anyone know about another option, or can tell me wrong about the statements above?

Comment: What is the meaning of "bandwidth are different per dimension but the method is non parametric." supposed to be? KDE is nonparametric, `KDEMultivariate` has 4 options for bandwidth choice.

Comment: @Josef Thanks. I edited the question, I had said it wrong.